# "Can't find starting number (in the name of file)" when trying to read frames from hevc (h265) video in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to read frames from a `hevc(h265)` .avi video in `opencv-python` (python3, latest version) but keeps throwing

> **OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253:
>   error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in
>   the name of file): C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\2019-11-22_13\a.avi in
>   function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'**.

I've tried both in `ubuntu` and `windows 10` using `opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python and opencv-contrib-python-nonfree`, but it didn't work. 
Thank you in advance.

Code used to read the video:

```py
import cv2
import imutils

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\gabri\\Desktop\\2019-11-22_13\\a.avi")


while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    frame = imutils.resize(frame,width = 960)
    cv2.imshow('image',frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff

    if k == 27:
       break
```

Comment: I am not sure if that's your case but you need to set the codec as already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392455/opencv-videocapture-with-h264-codec

Comment: Did  you  try it with  cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '5')); ?

Comment: I've had the same error while trying to open a file in the wrong directory, so the error message was completely misleading, should have been "File not found".

Answer (score 17):

You can get this error in the `VideoWriter` class if you do not specify your extension in the file name In my case I have forgotten to write `.mp4`.

Comment: In my case there was an extra space after mpeg

Answer (score 8):

this error normally pop-up when video_path in functions `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video_path")` or `cv2.VideoWriter('path_to_folder/output_save.avi')` is not correct
Mostly seen in windows

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this by passing the absolute path into `VideoCapture` and changing the filename from `example.mov` to `example_1000.mov`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, compilation and linking ok, but the same cryptic error occurs at running.

It happened (with Windows) when `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg430_64.dll` was not accessible (it seems to be silently called by another opencv lib). Either you did not build opencv with the `-DWITH_FFMPEG=ON`, or alternatively your dll is not in the path.

Comment: I had this same issue (on Ubuntu), which I resolved by adding ffmpeg to my OpenCV build. For future readers: If you build OpenCV yourself, look through the output of cmake for `FFMPEG: YES`. If you see `FFMPEG: NO`, then cmake was not able to locate the development files for ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and solved it by changing the video name to '001.avi'.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can append a number to your path like 'a2.avi' instead of 'a.avi'.

Comment: "*Maybe you can append a number to your path*", maybe you wanted to say "*to your filename*"?

Comment: Consider adding an explanation for making such a change. Also, often the file path will be taken as an input, which we'll have to use as it is regardless of the whatever filename we are given

Comment: Why would that fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

File extension was missing in my case: changing `movie` to `movie.mp4` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

My use case is probably not what is being asked in the question however since the error message produced by opencv is slightly misleading I'll leave a note for others who might encounter similar problem.

In my case I was receiving following error because the file was corrupted:

```
OpenCV(4.5.1) cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): /path/to/file.png in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

I was receiving files through AWS API gateway and in order to avoid files being corrupted I had to add 'multipart/form-data' within 'Binary Media Types' section of APIGateway app settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the filename needs to have a number on it. So in your case perhaps you can rename your file to **a0.avi**

Comment: CAP_IMAGES is the last reader module that is tried, meaning the usual modules (for video files and for camera devices) failed to make sense of the file name you passed or the file's content. -- CAP_IMAGES is for _image_ sequences, i.e. numbered file names... for _video files_, no such logic exists. your perceived requirement does not exist and adding numbers to the name of a video file does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error occurred before I was able to approve access to the camera. After I approved the use of the camera for the application, it worked.

Comment: How do you approve access to a camera???